# CGContextDrawRadialGradient For Non-Circular Glow

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I'm able to use `CGContextDrawRadialGradient` to make a sphere that does an alpha fade to `UIColor.clearColor` and it works.

However, I'm trying to do this type of thing:

[image]

While placing some strategic spheres around makes for an interesting effect (similar to LED backlights in strategic places), I would love to get a true glow. **How can I draw a glow around a rounded rectangle in `drawRect`?**

Comment: Would a colored shadow be sufficient?

Comment: @IanHenry not really because it would end abruptly instead of gradually alpha'ing out. I realize that I could do a few "rings" of varying alpha's, but I'm looking for something less hacky.

Comment: The blur of the shadow can be changed in `CGContextSetShadowWithColor`; that allows you to do something very similar to the image you've shown (you don't get precise control over the shadow gradient, though).

Comment: @IanHenry I will check that out, then. I don't need that much control as long as it looks good ;) On the other hand, if you want to put up an answer with a tiny little example image/code/both, that would be good for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a glow effect around any path using `CGContextSetShadowWithColor`, but you don't get precise control over the appearance. In particular, the default shadow is fairly light:

[image: the default shadow]

And the only way I know of to make it darker is to draw it again over itself:

[image]

Not optimal, but it approximates what you want pretty well.

Those images were generated by the following `drawRect`:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

    int padding = 20;
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, padding, padding);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, rect.size.width - padding, rect.size.height / 2);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, padding, rect.size.height - padding);

    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeZero, 20, UIColor.redColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.blueColor.CGColor);

    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
    // CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    // CGContextFillPath(context);

    CGPathRelease(path);
}
```

One thing to bear in mind is that rendering fuzzy shadows is fairly expensive, which may or may not be a problem depending on how often your views are redrawn. If the shadows don't need to animate, consider rendering them to a `UIImage` once and just displaying the result in a `UIImageView`.

Comment: do you think it's more expensive than 2-color gradients? My guess would be that it'd be similar.

Comment: If you're drawing a radial gradient it's probably cheaper than a shadow for an arbitrary path, but if you figured out a way to draw the gradients in the same shape as the shadow then it's probably exactly the same. Only testing will tell!

Comment: I'll put that in the "to test" bin, which is quite large and rarely gets emptied (unless there's a performance or memory prob). Thanks again

Comment: Testing revealed performance problems with this type of drawing. However, you don't have to render to a `UIImage`if you can manage to get `drawRect` not to fire, which is generally quite easy.

Comment: You might want to look into `CALayer`'s `shouldRasterize` property if the shadow never changes. It can give you great performance improvements with minimal effort, but has its limitations. (If you do use it, make sure you set the `rasterizationScale` to `UIScreen.mainScreen.scale` as well)

Comment: It really does change often. The issue is that it doesn't have to. There's almost always an architectural win that makes the user feel just fine, too :)

Comment: What's wrong with my shadow? Its not showing at all!
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeZero, 200, UIColor.redColor.CGColor);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.blueColor.CGColor);

those two lines don't do anything