# drawRect draw a thin line with a big shadow

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawrect, cgcontext, quartz-core

**SITUATION**

I've drawn a thin line via `CGContextAddLineToPoint` and `CGContextStrokePath`. I added a red shadow via `CGContextSetShadowWithColor`.

**DESIRED BEHAVIOR**

No matter what value I set for the blur, the red shadow was too weak. I would like the red shadow to be much much stronger.

**NOTE**

The white line with red shadow is placed on top of an image, not a flat color, so I can't use a flat color to fake it.

Also, the white line can be curved (I use `CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint`).

**WHAT I TRIED**

Playing around with `CGContextSetLineWidth`, I found that increasing the width made the red shadow more noticeable. However, the white line was then too thick.

I then tried splitting it the drawing into two parts with the shadow using a larger line width. When I tried drawing just the shadow with `[[UIColor clearColor] setStroke]`, the shadow wasn't drawn at all.

I then tried drawing just the shadow with `[[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.1] setStroke]` but having an alpha on the stroke ALSO affects the alpha of the shadow, so the shadow was still too weak.

I tried following [iOS Core Graphics: Draw ONLY shadows of a CGPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170678/ios-core-graphics-draw-only-shadows-of-a-cgpath) but I got a weird effect where not only did my shadows not show, but the line was fading from red to black. I wasn't sure what was going on.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show a picture of what you are trying to achieve? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following [CGContextDrawRadialGradient For Non-Circular Glow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080405/cgcontextdrawradialgradient-for-non-circular-glow). Essentially I redrew the line on top of itself multiple times until the glow looked strong enough. I also rasterized it in the hopes that the performance hit won't be too harsh.